# iOS safari update element while scrolling

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I want to get the similar behavior for my header in HTML page as in ios google chrome's header: when user start to scroll to the top (from any place of the page) of the page header appears as if it was sitting just above. And when user is scrolling to the bottom - the header just keeps it's position and slides up.

I added a 'touchmove' event to capture scroll coordinates, and can log it in some div just to check if it is working and seems like it's working fine, except for header's position is not updating while scrolling. Once scroll has stopped header's position updated as expected.

So my question: is it possible to update an element while user is scrolling?

I would prefer to not change to scrolling the content of the element (instead of scrolling the page itself).

Seems like no workaround, from Jquery.mobile page:

> Triggers when a scroll begins. Note that iOS devices freeze DOM
>   manipulation during scroll, queuing them to apply when the scroll
>   finishes. We're currently investigating ways to allow DOM
>   manipulations to apply before a scroll starts.

Answer (score 1):

Do you by any chance have some code we can look at?

Although, if you're using jQuery, check out this plugin: http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/

It provides the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Doesn't really matter the code can be just something like $(document).on('touchmove', function(){ $('#target').css('top', (value + 1) + 'px')}), if you will be able to show me how to change an element during user is scrolling (say change background color or position preferably) i will accept the answer.

Comment: Thank for the link, i have done something similar myself, but it doesn't suit my customers :(

Comment: Thanks, that actually was an interesting idea - to use timeouts, but it doesn't work either. I guess ios just freeze layout and JS during scroll, i can understand reasons for this, just thought maybe there is workaround. Have you seen google chrom on ios? It's hard to explain what exact behavior i'm trying to achieve... First, the header should move with scroll, not scroll initiates animation of the header.

Comment: What actually happens is that the DOM drawing is paused, the js code execution is not blocked.
This article gives a good understanding:
http://developer.telerik.com/featured/scroll-event-change-ios-8-big-deal/